# Find repository where sbt finds a plugin or JAR

Tags: scala, plugins, dependencies, sbt, dependency-management

Trying to troubleshoot an `sbt` build, would like to know which pattern in `sbt.repositories` matches a given triple.

I have a plugin and two `sbt` builds. One build finds the plugin and the other does not. Both builds use `sbt.repositories` files to override external repos with internal sites (behind corporate firewall).

The `sbt.repositories` files are different between the two builds, so I suspect that one of them is missing a pattern that would match the plugin. The `sbt.repositories` files are large enough that I would prefer to not do this by hand, or by trial and error.

I would like to use `sbt`'s own facilities to print messages such as "using pattern (some pattern from `sbt.repositories`) I have found plugin (org,name,ver) at (some URL)".

The patterns from `sbt.repositories` have the format below. `sbt` must be looping through these patterns, computing all the combinations and testing  whether the result is a valid URL. I would like to access that class myself, so I can find out which pattern from `sbt.repositories` allows one build to find the plugin (or JAR). Then I would add that pattern to the `sbt.repositories` of the other build.

Does anyone know whether this functionality is available through the build DSL (i.e. from `build.sbt`) or the name of the resolver class that does this for `sbt`?

```
sbt.repositories
repo-name = http://some.internal.website.com:1234/artifacts/releases,[organisation]/[module](/scala_[scalaVersion])(/sbt_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[artifact](-[classifier])(-[revision]).[ext]
```

I have tried `sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true --debug clean update compile > someLogFile.txt`, and this tells me which plugins are found, including the one I am interested in, but not **where** they were found.

Comment: I don't know how to find it through sbt, but this file might give you a hint about which pattern to add: `<userprofile>\.ivy2\cache\<pathToDependency>\ivydata-<version>.properties`

Comment: I could try to write my own `Resolver` by adding logging statements to https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/api/index.html#sbt.Resolver$$url$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote something quick and dirty, but it works for me. I would be happy to see a solution that uses the Ivy resolver, which must provide the same functionality, only more reliably.

In my experience, because it is difficult for humans to understand if a pattern like `[organisation]/[module](/scala_[scalaVersion])(/sbt_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[artifact](-[classifier])(-[revision]).[ext]` matches what they need or duplicates another pattern that already exists in `sbt.repositories`, people just copy-paste patterns from one repo file into another until the build works. Over time, this creates a tangled mess, and we need to tools to handle questions such as "which pattern matches a given dependency" or "which two patterns are identical", or "which pattern does not match any dependencies", etc.

```
import java.io.File
import java.net.URL
import java.util.regex.Pattern

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.io.{Codec, Source}
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

object FindDependency {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val root = new File(".")
    val sbtRepos = new File(root, "./build/sbt.repositories")

    implicit val dep = Dep(organisation = "com.foo.bar.sbt", module = "baz", artifact = "baz", revision = "1.2.3-SNAPSHOT", ext = "jar"
      , scalaVersion = "2.10", sbtVersion = "0.13", artType = "jar", classifier = "")

    println(sbtRepos.getCanonicalPath + ": exists?" + sbtRepos.exists)
    processSbtRepos(sbtRepos)
  }

  def processSbtRepos(repoFilePath: File)(implicit dep: Dep): Unit = {
    val source = Source.fromFile(repoFilePath)(Codec.ISO8859)
    source.getLines.foreach { line =>
      if (!ignore(line)) {
        println(s"\n$line")
        val namePattern = line.split(":") map (_.trim)
        if (namePattern.length >= 3) artifactUrl(namePattern)
      }
    }
    source.close
  }

  def artifactUrl(words: Array[String])(implicit dep: Dep): Unit = {
    val artBase = repoUrl(words)
    val artifactPattern = if (artBase.indexOf('[') > 0) artBase else artBase + ",[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
    val artUrls = dep.potentialUrls(artifactPattern)
    artUrls.foreach { url =>
      if (isValidUrl(url)) {
        println(s"$artifactPattern -> $url")
      }
    }
  }

  def isValidUrl(url: String): Boolean = {
    try {
      val u = new URL(url)
      val contentLength = u.openConnection.getContentLength
      val openStream = u.openStream
      val binaryData = new Array[Byte](contentLength)
      openStream.read(binaryData)
      openStream.close
      true
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(_) => false
    }
  }

  def repoUrl(words: Array[String]): String = words.drop(1).mkString(":")

  def ignore(line: String): Boolean = {
    line.indexOf("http://") < 0
  }

}

/**
  * Represents a dependency
  *
  * @param artType artifact type, e.g. "sources", "javadoc", ""
  */
case class Dep(organisation: String, module: String, artifact: String, revision: String
               , ext: String, scalaVersion: String, sbtVersion: String, artType: String
               , classifier: String) {
  /**
    * Given a pattern and the known parameters for a dependency, replace the details of the dependency in the pattern.
    *
    * @return a concrete URL (with optional portions) where the dependency may be located
    */
  def replace(pattern: String): String = {
    pattern.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[artifact]"), artifact)
      .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[ext]"), ext)
      .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[module]"), module)
      .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[organisation]"), organisation)
      .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[organization]"), organisation)
      .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[revision]"), revision)
      .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[scalaVersion]"), scalaVersion)
      .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[sbtVersion]"), sbtVersion)
      .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[type]"), artType)
      .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("[classifier]"), classifier)
  }

  def potentialUrls(pattern: String): Seq[String] = {
    val urlWithOpts = replace(pattern)
      .replaceAll(" ", "")
      .replaceAll(",", "/")
      .replaceAll("\\(", "(?") // mark the optional elements with the prefix "?"
    val words = urlWithOpts.split("\\(|\\)").map(_.trim).filterNot(_.isEmpty).filterNot(_ == "?-")
    val urls = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
    val urlsCrt = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String] // a temp container for urls
    urls.add(words(0)) // the first "word" is the repo URL, which is not optional
    words.drop(1).foreach { word =>
      // transfer the current list of URLs to the temp container
      urlsCrt.clear
      urlsCrt ++= urls
      urls.clear
      if (word.startsWith("?")) {
        // append all URLs that were there before, unchanged (because this word is optional)
        urls ++= urlsCrt
        // as well as all URLs that were there before, each concatenated with this word
        urls ++= urlsCrt.map(_ + word.substring(1))
      } else {
        // to each URL that was there before, concatenate the new word
        urls ++= urlsCrt.map(_ + word)
      }
    }
    urls
  }
}
```